# Who's in charge of selecting the Quidditch Captain?

Tags: harry-potter, hogwarts, quidditch

We see that in his sixth year, Harry is made captain of the Gryffindor Quidditch team. Who selects the Quidditch Captain for each house? Would it just be McGonagall as she is the Head of the House of Gryffindor or does more thought go into it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## It’s decided at Hogwarts, and put in a letter.

It isn’t made clear *who* exactly of the Hogwarts staff chooses the Quidditch Captain, but it is definitely either one or more of the Hogwarts staff choosing the Quidditch Captain, since Harry finds out that he’s been made Captain in his Hogwarts letter.

> “The day after this rather gloomy birthday tea, their letters and book lists arrived from Hogwarts. Harry’s included a surprise: he had been made Quidditch Captain.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 6 (Draco’s Detour)*</sup></sub>

The Quidditch team they’ll be Captain of doesn’t seem to have any say in who they’ll get as Captain, because Harry doesn’t know who the new Gryffindor Captain is until she tells him.

> “Hi,’ she said briskly, ‘good summer?’ And without waiting for an answer, ‘Listen, I’ve been made Gryffindor Quidditch Captain.’
>
> ‘Nice one,’ said Harry, grinning at her; he suspected Angelina’s pep talks might not be as long-winded as Oliver Wood’s had been, which could only be an improvement.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 12 (Professor Umbridge)*</sup></sub>

It’s certainly staff at Hogwarts doing the choosing, but it’s unclear from the information given exactly which staff members are involved in the selection process.

## The Captain’s Head of House can revoke it.

Though it doesn’t necessarily mean they’re the ones actually choosing the Quidditch Captain, the Head of a Captain’s house does have the power to take away the position, since Professor McGonagall threatens the Gryffindor Quidditch Captain with losing her captaincy if she continues misbehaving.

> “Because detentions do not appear to have any effect on you whatsoever!’ said Professor McGonagall tartly. ‘No, not another word of complaint, Potter! And as for you, Miss Johnson, you will confine your shouting matches to the Quidditch pitch in future or risk losing the team captaincy!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 15 (The Hogwarts High Inquisitor)*</sup></sub>

Therefore, the Head of a Captain’s house presumably has the authority to revoke their position on their own.

Comment: I suspect there's some sort of whimsical Quidditch-Captain-choosing-piece-of-magical-clothing. "*Tell us, oh Sorting Sock, who will be the Gryffindor captain?"*

Comment: That check is for the last point about revoking captain privileges.

Comment: We only know for sure that McGonagall can initiate the process of revoking the position. Se says "**risk** losing", not "**will** lose". It could be her authority as Head of House, her authority as Deputy Headmistress, or just a suggestion to the Headmaster.

Answer (score 4):

### Either the Headmaster or the Head of House.

I suspect that the process for selecting Quidditch captains is similar to that of selecting prefects and the Head Boy/Girl. They *are* different roles, but they're all positions of responsibility which are given to students who are adjudged to be capable, diligent and mature.

We know that prefects are chosen by the Headmaster, as it was Dumbledore who overlooked Harry for the role of prefect.

> “I feel I owe you another explanation, Harry,” said Dumbledore hesitantly. “You may, perhaps, have wondered why I never chose you as a prefect? I must confess...that I rather thought...you had enough responsibility to be going on with.”
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 37, The Lost Prophecy)*.</sub>

Whether the Headmaster actually shortlists and picks the Quidditch captain, or whether they just rubber stamp the decision of another staff member is unclear. There are only so many people who could pick the captain, and the Head of House is the only other credible option. There's no indication that Madame Hooch, for instance, would have any say. She only referees the games; she probably wouldn't get involved in managing the teams.

The Head of House has a close affinity to the team. Any time there's a need for teacher involvement in the team it's the Head of House that takes authority. It's McGonagall who recommends that Harry be the next Gryffindor Seeker. It's McGonagall who arranges for the 'no brooms for first years' rule to be bent, and who buys Harry a broom. It's McGonagall who arranges for Madame Hooch to supervise the Gryffindor training sessions. It's Snape who grants permission for the Slytherins to use the pitch in *Chamber of Secrets*. It's McGonagall who handles indiscipline in the team in *Order of the Phoenix* (before she's undermined by Umbridge). And, as Bellatrix points out, it's McGonagall who apparently has the power to change the Quidditch captain if she so chooses.

> "No, not another word of complaint, Potter! And as for you, Miss Johnson, you will confine your shouting matches to the Quidditch pitch in future or risk losing the team captaincy!"
>   <sub>*(Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 15, The Hogwarts High Inquisitor)*.</sub>

Again, it's not entirely clear whether she would make this decision herself, or whether she'd recommend that Dumbledore remove the captaincy. Either way, she evidently has some clout in determining whether there's a change of captain or not.

I would suggest that both the Headmaster and the Head of House have a role in selecting the captain. It's not clear which one makes the initial decision and which merely authorises the selection. Since the Head of House is the most invested in the team it would make sense for them to pick the captain and inform the Headmaster of their decision, and for the Headmaster to subsequently confirm or deny that selection. We don't any definitive clarification in the books, however.

Comment: For me it's much more likely for a Head of House to select a Captain. She/he wants good fame of her/his house and would choose the best candidate (in her/his opinion of course). The Headmaster should be objective and avoid being accused of partiality by damaging some teams with choosing weak captains. I recall Lupin saying that as a teacher he didn't support any team. This should apply also to the Headmaster.